# SEAM navigation based on function with parameters

Tags: java, jsf, navigation, seam

How do you setup a navigation rule based on a function with parameters in SEAM ?

For example

```
<page view-id="/firstPage.xhtml" back="enabled">
    <navigation from-action="#{actionBean.fetchItem(int index)}">
        <redirect view-id="/itemDetail.xhtml" />
    </navigation>
</page>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible,

But... *from-action* signature **must match** your commandButton, commandLink, etc *action* attribute

Suppose your command is shown as follows

```
<h:commandButton action="#{actionBean.fetchItem(index)}" value="Submit index"/>
```

...

Now your navigation

```
<page view-id="/firstPage.xhtml" back="enabled">
    <navigation from-action="#{actionBean.fetchItem(index)}">
        <redirect view-id="/itemDetail.xhtml" />
    </navigation>
</page>
```

Comment: Certainly does work in the way you described, although I ended up using what @Bozho suggested. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't get it why do you need a parameter, when you are going to have one outcome for *all* parameters.

If it is indeed what you want - well, then don't use any parameters.

If you want to execute the action and then return to the view - well, you can return the appropriate `String` from your action method.